# Get assembly version in PCL

Tags: .net-assembly, portable-class-library, system.reflection

I have the following line of code in .NET 4.5 that I am trying to build as Portable Class Library. It's purpose is to get assembly version:

```
this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version.Major;
```

The problem is that Assembly.GetName() is not available in PCL. Is there a way to get assembly version in PCL?

I know it is possible to parse Assembly.FullName, but I want a better solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
    public static string Version
    {
        get
        {
            var assembly = typeof(MyType).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            // In some PCL profiles the above line is: var assembly = typeof(MyType).Assembly;
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(assembly.FullName);
            return assemblyName.Version.Major + "." + assemblyName.Version.Minor;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`. First, it's quite expensive and secondly it has all sort of problems w.r.t. when the call side is being inlined. Thus, we don't expose it in Windows Store. In static methods you can use `typeof(MyType).GetTypeInfo().Assembly`. In instance methods you should use `GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that. There is no GetTypeInfo() available in my PCL (Profile95), but I can call Assembly directly on the type.

Comment: You're correct. GetTypeInfo() is only available to post .NET 4.5 platforms (.NET 4.5, Windows Store and Windows Phone 8).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for a late reply. I tried your suggestion but for some reason I can not use the Type.Assembly property in PCL. I am targeting .NET 4.5, Store and Windows Phone 8. According to docs it should work but for some reason it doesn't.

Comment: @kls I have updated my answer to show both variants.

Answer (score 7):

I now use the following:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyTitle)]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyProduct)]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion)]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyFileVersion)]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyInformationalVersion)]

internal class AssemblyInfo
{
    public const string AssemblyTitle = "...";
    public const string AssemblyProduct = "...";

    public const string AssemblyVersion = "1.0.0.0";
    public const string AssemblyFileVersion = "1.0.0.0";
    public const string AssemblyInformationalVersion = "1.0.0.0-dev";
}
```

This allows me to reference any of the constants within the assembly without using reflection, e.g. `AssemblyInfo.AssemblyProduct`.

Comment: This is a great suggestion! I normally move my semantic version information to a shared file, this is a easy change.

Answer (score 2):

You are targeting a Silverlight-based platform (Silverlight 4 or higher, Windows Phone before version 8). Those platforms didnt' support the `GetName()` method. For those platforms, you can define an extension method like this:

```
public static class AssemblyExtensions
{
    public static AssemblyName GetName(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        return new AssemblyName(assembly.FullName);
    }
}
```